# $X$ infinite compact Hausdorff. Existence of disjointly supported sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset C\big(X,[0,1]\big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

I'm wondering (as the title says) if, given a compact Hausdorff space $X$ with infinite cardinality, there exists a nontrivial disjointly supported sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset C\big(X,[0,1]\big)$.

Let $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ be a sequence in $X$ with no repetitions (possible because $X$ is infinite). It seems that I will definitely need to assume that $\{x_n\}\cap\overline{\{x_j\}_{j\neq n}}=\varnothing$ for each $n$. The problem is, I'm not sure if I can just remove points or something and assume that the set of accumulation points of $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is disjoint from $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ itself. I currently can't come up with counterexample to this, but I know there are some ugly topologies out there which might admit even a sequence in which *every* point of the sequence is an accumulation point of the sequence. However compact Hausdorff spaces are pretty well behaved, so I'm willing to believe not.

If I can do this I believe by exploiting the normality of $X$ I can find for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ an open set $U_n$ and closed set $F_n$ such that $x_n\in F_n\subset U_n$ and $U_n\cap\overline{\{x_j\}_{j\neq n}}=\varnothing$. Applying Uyrsohn's lemma should then yield the desired sequence.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easier way to see such a sequence of functions exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think these $f_n$ need to have disjoint supports. There could be lots of points in $X$ other than the $x_j$.

Comment: Just a technicality, but you probably want to add the condition that none of the $f_n$ is identically zero, otherwise you can get trivial sequences that satisfy your requirements.

Comment: You're right. I'm dumb. I'll rephrase my question and resubmit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the space is infinite (and Hausdorff), you may find an infinite sequence $(U_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of pairwise-disjoint open sets. Pick $x_n\in U_n$. Then you may find $f_n\in C(X,[0,1])$ such that $f_n$ is constantly equal to 0 in $X\setminus U_n$ and $f(x_n)=1$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$).